# Get the two most common values of an attribute in a xml nodeset

Tags: r, xml

I parsed a pdf document to xml and have a xml nodeset (called textNodes) of some xml nodes which all look something like:

```
<text top="109" left="413" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>
```

I now need the two most common "left" values of this page. What works is:

```
          typicalLeftValues <- sort(
        as.integer(names(head(sort(table(unlist(purrr::map(xml2::xml_attrs(textNodes), "left"))), 
                                   decreasing = TRUE), 2))))
```

I am using purrr and xml2 for this. But I cannot imagine that this is the most efficient solution. While it works, it just looks odd and feels rather slow. In addition, I would like to avoid the dependency on purrr (or any package other than xml2) if possible.

So the question: How would I get the two most common values of an attribute in a xml nodeset?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml2 package is vectorized, thus there shouldn't be a need for the purr package is this case.  Using the example code from above, I was able to extract all of the nodes and process them in one step.

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

Nodes<-read_xml('<Nodes><text top="109" left="413" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>
                    <text top="109" left="423" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>
                    <text top="109" left="423" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>
                    <text top="109" left="423" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>
                    <text top="109" left="400" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>
                    <text top="109" left="413" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>
                    <text top="109" left="423" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>
                    </Nodes>')

#find all of the text nodes
#extract out the "left attribute
#convert to integer
#use table function to find the counts
#sort in decreasing order
textNodescounts<-xml_find_all(Nodes, "//text") %>% xml_attr("left") %>% as.integer() %>% table() %>% sort(decreasing=TRUE)
#return the first two elements
textNodescounts[1:2]
```

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick superbly! I was hoping that someone would say "dude, it's vectorized, just do it like that..". It is actually way faster than my solution. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your actual data, this could be a start in base R:

```
textNodes <- c('<text top="109" left="413" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>',
  '<text top="109" left="423" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>',
  '<text top="109" left="423" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>',
  '<text top="109" left="423" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>',
  '<text top="109" left="400" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>',
  '<text top="109" left="413" width="70" height="15" font="7">\n  <b>Hello</b>\n</text>')

(want <- sort(table(unlist(lapply(textNodes, function(x) {
  dummy <- strsplit(gsub("[\n\"]", "", x), " ")[[1]]
  substr(dummy[substr(dummy, 1, 5) == "left="], 6, length(dummy))
}))), dec = TRUE)[1:2])

#423 413 
#  3   2
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a good solution if you wan't to circumvent any usage of other packages except for base R. I actually think that it's really nice and instructive. However the solution above is way faster. But thank you for helping out :)